# How to select time range in POSIXct format when time range spans two dates?

Tags: r, posixct

I am trying to select a range of time that spans across 2 days (e.g. 2011-01-01 17:00:00 to 2011-01-02 05:00:00) to compute an average of some variable (e.g. wind speed) during that time interval.

Sample data:

```
## Create a record and some random data for every 15 min 
## over 10 days for windspeed.
dates <- seq(as.POSIXct("2011-01-01 00:00:00", tz = "GMT"),
         as.POSIXct("2011-01-10 23:59:00", tz = "GMT"),
         by = 900)
windspeed <- sample(0:20, length(dates), replace = TRUE)
Data  <- data.frame(dates = dates, windspeed = windspeed)
```

I was able to filter the dates I was interested in from my dataset using the dplyr package:

```
Data %>%
filter(dates > ymd_hms("2011-01-01 00:00:00", tz = GMT) & dates < ymd_hms("2011-01-04 00:00:00", tz = GMT) | dates > ymd_hms("2011-01-06 00:00:00", tz = GMT) & dates < ymd_hms("2011-01-010 00:00:00", tz = GMT))
```

Is there a wildcard that I could use in place of the DATE in the above code and only specify the time interval of interest? Or some other method of computing the average over a time interval regardless of the date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new column specifying if the date/time falls into a given interval using e.g `cut.POSIXt()`:

We first create some breaks to create the intervals based on your min and max POSIXts:

```
breaks <- seq(floor_date(min(Data$dates), unit = "days") + hms("17:00:00"), ceiling_date(max(Data$dates), unit = "days"), by = "12 hour")
```

Then put your date/times into bins with `cut`:

```
Data$lev <- cut.POSIXt(Data$dates, breaks = breaks, labels = 1:(length(breaks)-1))
```

Then just select those (odd) bins that contain the desired groups (from 17:00:00 to 05:00:00)

```
filter(Data, lev %in% seq(1 , max( as.numeric(as.character(unique(Data$lev))), na.rm = T ), by =2) )%>% 
  group_by(lev) %>% summarise(means  = mean(windspeed))

     lev     means
1      1 10.416667
2      3 10.625000
3      5 11.000000
4      7  9.979167
5      9 11.104167
6     11  9.562500
7     13  9.895833
8     15  9.937500
9     17 10.625000
```

PS, `cut()` is set by default right = TRUE, which means that the interval will be closed to the right. You need to adjust this accordingly.

Comment: I see what you are getting at, but in your example you are still defining the ymd in your break.  My dataset spans over a hundred days and I am looking for a way to select the time interval from 17:00:00 on day 1 to 05:00:00 on day 2, 17:00:00 on day 2 to 05:00:00 on day 3, so on and so forth.  So I am looking for a way to filter out that time interval regardless of the date.

Comment: Great! Your explanation of the cut() function was really helpful. Your answer is spot on.